# How to download python with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically what I'm trying to do is to download python with a python file. It needs to be so that user does not have to interact with the python installer at all. They just click the file and python is installed on the computer. I don't need pip I just need the computer to be able to read .py files. I seem to only be able to download the installer which the user then must open. 
What would the solution to this be?

I'm using python 3.6. Also, the file must be able to be compiled to .exe so something built into python and not a module from the internet would be best (I sometimes have trouble compiling files with modules from the internet with pyinstaller) but I'm open to anything.

This is my first question so I might be doing something wrong...

Comment: Script the msi and you'll be sorted

Answer (score 1):

You will want to start by developing a python script that does any function you want it to do. In this case, it looks like you want it to download python and install it without user interaction and you want to be able to run this as an executable on windows. So your process would be as follows.

`your_script_name.py`

This contains all the code to download and install python non-interactive.

Then to convert this into windows`.exe` install pyinstaller then run the following.

`pyinstaller --onefile <your_script_name>.py`

This will result in  `your_script_name.exe`

#### Note: You need to run pyinstaller on a windows system for it to produce an `.exe`